# Two-state CSS-only rollover without JavaScript

Tags: css

I am trying to create a two-state CSS rollover, so when the user rolls over a box, the box changes color and another image appears to the side, and when they roll off the image to the side it disappears and the box reverts to the original state.

The page I am working on is here:

http://www.philippedollo.com/assign.htm

Is there any standards-compliant way to do this without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quick example using a link and the hover property in CSS.  You'll have to replace the `.twoStateInner` `span` with your image (and add `float:left` to it, changing the order of that and the other `span` to swap sides the image will apear on), and change the color as desired in your .twoState:hover CSS.

HTML:

```
<a class="twoState" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span>text&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="twoStateInner">foo</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.twoStateInner {
    display: none;
}

.twoState div {
    float: left;
}

.twoState:hover .twoStateInner {
    display: block;
}

.twoState:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Also, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/PTkv8/)'s a fiddle where you can see this in action.

**UPDATE:**

Changed `div` tags to `span` tags within the link based on Smirkin Gherkin's comment, as `spans` within links are standards compliant.

Comment: I think that might work, do you see any issues with doing that with two unordered lists (one for the link, the other containing the images)?

Comment: @user784576 The bottom line is that you need a common parent that supports and uses the CSS :hover attribute, and both elements need to be children of that.  The "a" tag is the one that is most widely supported for :hover, but you could look into using other elements if you know which browser(s) and versions your users will be on.  I'd have to see your code to see what you mean, but as long as the above principles are applied, you should be good to go.

Comment: @Briguy37 - as far as I am aware the only mainstream browser that doesn't support `:hover` on elements that are not `a` is IE6. The question asked for a standards compliant solution and you have a block element (`div`) as a child of an inline element (`a`) which is not standards compliant. There is a solution using conditional comments that is standards compliant for a CSS menu at [CSSplay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/latest-flyout.html) which could be adapted.

Comment: @Smirkin Gherkin:  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the `divs` to `spans` based on your comments.  Also, you could ignore the incompatibility of IE6 since it will be phased out soon and just use the hovers on whatever element you choose.

Comment: @Briguy: I would love to say yes on the IE6 front, but I can't. On the sites that I have control over (UK) based the level of IE6 usage in recent months has fallen but it still accounts for over 5% so a significant number of users would have issues. I would be tempted to say that a JavaScript solution for IE6 would cover most people as this would allow graceful degredation for most people. It depends on the levels of support that you want to provide. Personally I implement the compliant IE6 support and curse the browser that doesn't die.